# Restricting data usage monitoring to certain days

Tags: mobile-data, data-monitoring

My data plan includes unlimited data during the weekend (so any data usage during the weekend is not taken off the 50Go afforded by the plan), and I would like to monitor my data usage taking this into account.

I could not find any setting/application that allows to restrict the monitoring to certain days, did I miss one?

Comment: App recommendations are off topic. Edited slightly to make it on topic

Answer (score 1):

[Glass Wire Data Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.glasswire.android) let's you customize your monitoring period. But it has to be done manually every week

[image: IMG:]

(Click to enlarge)